# Load JSON into ComboBox in ExtJS

Tags: ajax, json, jsp, servlets, extjs

I am new to both `jsp` and `ExtJS`. I have a `jsp` file from which am sending an `AJAX` request to a `servlet`. The `servlet` returns a `JSON` as a `String`. After receiving the `JSON`, i have to populate a `ComboBox`. Though the `servlet` is returning the `JSON`, my `ComboBox` is unable to load the data.

Here are some snippets from my code.

The `servlet` code to generate the `JSON`:

```
            ...

            String sql = "SELECT DISTINCT category FROM ProductTable ORDER BY category";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
            while (rs.next()) {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                String cat = rs.getString("category");
                obj.put("category", cat);
                list.add(obj);
            }
            JSONObject resultObject = new JSONObject();
            resultObject.put("result", list);
            StringWriter output = new StringWriter();
            resultObject.writeJSONString(output);
            String jsonText = output.toString();
            System.out.print(jsonText);

            ...

            response.setContentType("text/plain");
            response.getWriter().write(jsonText);
```

The `jsp` code:

```
    ...

    $.get('LoadDropDown', {
        label : "category"
    }, function(responseText) {
        JSONForCategory = Ext.JSON.decode(responseText);
        console.log(JSONForCategory);
    });

    ...

    {
        xtype : 'combo',
        fieldLabel : 'Category',
        name : 'category',
        displayField : 'category',
        valueField : 'category',
        mode : 'local',
        triggerAction : 'all',
        store : new Ext.data.JsonStore({
            autoLoad : true,
            data : JSONForCategory,
            root : 'result',
            fields : [ 'category' ]
            })
    }
```

Could someone please tell me where am going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what does the line console.log(JSONForCategory); print?

Comment: It prints: Object {result: Array[39]}

Comment: Do yo have any reference to access data store?I ask ,i see you don't have any(not sure though)

Comment: No. I don't have any.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to keep reference of data store like below.

```
var dataStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
            autoLoad : true,
            data : JSONForCategory,
            root : 'result',
            fields : [ 'category' ]
});
```

Then you can refer to it from your `combo box` like below.

```
{
        xtype : 'combo',
        fieldLabel : 'Category',
        name : 'category',
        displayField : 'category',
        valueField : 'category',
        mode : 'local',
        triggerAction : 'all',
        store : dataStore 

}
```

and then from your ajax callback function,you can load the data to store like below.

```
JSONForCategory = Ext.JSON.decode(responseText);
console.log(JSONForCategory);
dataStore.loadData(JSONForCategory);
```

Comment: I added a reference store like you suggested. But no success. Am getting the following errors in my console -  1) Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) and 2) Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined. Is it because of these errors?

Comment: what does the line console.log(JSONForCategory); now?

Comment: `->Objects ->result: Array[39]`

Comment: so did you get the error when you use below line?dataStore.loadData(JSONForCategory); can you paste the stack trace of your console.

Comment: which version of ExtJS you are using?

Comment: I am getting the error even without using the line `dataStore.loadData(JSONForCategory);`

Comment: Here is the stack trace: `ext-all.js:21 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
ext-all.js:21 Ext.String.urlAppend
ext-all.js:21 Ext.apply.urlAppend
ext-all.js:21 Ext.cmd.derive.buildUrl
ext-all.js:21 Ext.cmd.derive.buildRequest
ext-all.js:21 Ext.cmd.derive.doRequest
ext-all.js:21 Ext.cmd.derive.read
ext-all.js:21 Ext.cmd.derive.load
ext-all.js:21 b.implement.callParent
ext-all.js:21 Ext.cmd.derive.load
ext-all.js:21 (anonymous function)

ext-all.js:21 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined`

Comment: ExtJS 5.1.0. Am also getting an error in the console which says its unable to retrieve the visgraph.js file. [link]http://localhost:8080/TestUI/scripts/visgraph.js

Comment: can you just replace Ext.data.JsonStore with Ext.data.Store and let me know?

Comment: Yep. The error is solved now. But the `combobox` isn't populating the `json`.

Comment: can you check,whether your store is loading data or not?

Comment: Could you please tell me how to check?

Comment: I tried `dataStore.on('load', function(){
    //do something
});` and it works.

Comment: ok,put   queryMode: 'local', and forceSelection: true, in combo box declaration  like other properties

Comment: Until now, i got a loading symbol when i clicked on the `combobox`. It isn't appearing now.

Comment: can you provide a [fiddle](http://fiddle.sencha.com) which replicates the issue, you could also load your `responseText` into here so that we can what the response is and can replicate it

Answer (score 0):

You can load your json file using ***data-options*** in html  tag by using the following method.

```
<input class="easyui-combobox" name="language" style="width:50%"
        data-options="
            url: 'combobox_data2.json', /* load your json file name */
            method: 'get',
            valueField:'value',
            textField:'text',
            groupField:'group'
        ">
```

Check [Combo Box](http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/demo/combobox/fluid.html) for reference.

Hope this will help you.